# Change dynamically the dropdown list value

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, forms, dropdown

I have a form where i list a related custom post type  by ID of the parent custom post type on a checkbox  list like the picture.

so when i check an option to 4 options i want to have a list of  the terms that  have the custom posts i checked  on the dropdown list.

the form is constructed with  elementor pro but to have the list of posts and  the taxonomy terms i do it with code (i do my function and i include it with shortcode on functions.php).

```
/*
 * Display list of  relationship field
 *
*/

function list_formation_caces(){
echo "<div class='golistgo'>";
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'categories',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $formations = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'formations',
        'post__in' => array(16061),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'categories', // name of custom field
                'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"', // matches exactly "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    ));
    if($formations){
        foreach ($formations as $categorie){
            $image = get_field('image_form');
            if($image){
                // Image variables.
                $url = $image['url'];
                $title = $image['title'];
                $alt = $image['alt'];
                $caption = $image['caption'];

                // Thumbnail size attributes.
                $size = 'thumbnail';
                $thumb = $image['sizes'][ $size ];
                $width = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-width' ];
                $height = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-height' ];
            }
            echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"btn-check\" name=\"Description\" value =\"". get_the_title() .
                "\" id=\"". get_the_ID()  ."\">";
            echo "<label class=\"options-form\" for='". get_the_ID() ."'>";
                               echo "<div class=\"image-cat\">";
                                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
                               echo"</div>";
                               echo "<div class=\"body-cat\">";
                                    echo "<div  class=\"title-formation\">" ;
                                    echo "</div>";
                                    echo "<div  class=\"title-cat\">" ;
                                    echo the_title() . ":" . " <span  class=\"describe-cat\">" . get_field('type_machine') . "</span>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                               echo "</div>";
            echo "</label>";
        }
    }
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
echo "</div>";
}

function shortcode_list_categ_caces(){
            return (list_formation_caces()) ;
}
add_shortcode('list_formation_caces', 'shortcode_list_categ_caces');

function shortcode_total_count_checked(){

return ("<div class='count-checkboxes-wrapper'>" . "<h2 class='title-count'>" . "Vous avez choisis" .
    "<span id='count-checked-checkboxes'> " . "  0" ."</span> catégorie(s)."." </h2>" .
    "</div>");
}
add_shortcode('count_checked', 'shortcode_total_count_checked');

function list_sessions_caces()
{
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'sessions',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );
    echo'<label for="form-field-centre" class="elementor-field-label">Où se déroulera la formation ?</label>';
    echo '<div class="elementor-field elementor-select-wrapper ">';
    echo '<select name="CENTRE"  id="form-field-field_centre" class="elementor-field-textual elementor-size-sm">';
    echo '<option value="">Choisir une session de formation </option> ';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo '<option value="' . $term->name . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo'</div>';
}
function shortcode_list_sessions(){
    return (list_sessions_caces()) ;
}
add_shortcode('list_sessions_caces', 'shortcode_list_sessions');
```

Any help, please!
[image]

Comment: It's not clear (to me at least) what should happen on what action. Can you be very specific? As in; This is an ... and when I click ... what should happen is ...

Comment: Sorry for that,
when  i check the value on checkbox  (where i list  the custom post) the dropdown of his taxonomy change dynamically with the value of this custom post.

Comment: Ok, (1.) I see no dropdown and no checkbox. I think you mean that the two portrait pictures are checkboxes and the two horizontal light-blue fields are dropdowns? 
Is that correct? (2.) You say that once you click a Custom Post Type you want the dropdown to change with the values 'of his taxonomy'. Is there a specific taxonomy for that Custom Post Type? Please be more specific, with all information there is (3.) Next to that, we need to see all of your code to be able to see what you attempt to do

Comment: Yes @JosFaber that's  it, you see it right.

ok  i have the code with it i get  the custom post type  on checkbox (portrait) , i will modify my question! just a minute

Comment: @JosFaber i do it you can check please :)

Answer (score 0):

You can go two ways:

1. There is probably not much data for the taxonomies of both CPT's, so you could render these two arrays in javascript from php in your template, and then switch the dropdown data on click of the checkbox. You could have the arrays named with the id's of the CPT's, e.g. `cpt-134` and then on click the CPT, set the dropdown data to the array named `cpt-[id-of-cpt]`. One way to get this data into your javascript is, if you e.g. have a `general.js`:

```
wp_register_script('general', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/general.js');
wp_localize_script('general', 'myVars', array(
  'site_url' => site_url(),
  'dropdownData' => get_CPT_Dropdown_Data(),
));
wp_enqueue_script('general');
```

You would ofcourse have to write that function `get_CPT_Dropdown_Data()` that returns the arrays with the taxonomy data, based on the CPT id's.

2. On click on the CPT, call an ajax function that you have made that retrieves the taxonomies for that CPT. Then update the dropdown with that data.

Option 2 is a more future-proof method (if things get bigger) and will not bloat your code with data that might not be needed. But it will add round trips to the server, so you might want to incorporate feedback for your users for when the loading starts.

Comment: the data in taxonomy will be like  just a text, can you help me with an example of  code  i'm noob with javascript sorry !   and how can i implement this on  my code ?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot code everything for you, for I don't have all the code. If you are using an existing theme, you would have to create your own child theme, because you have to write your own code to be able to do this. And you cannot use the built in code editor, because on an update, your code would be gone. Your best bet would be to write your own simple plugin in which you create the php function `get_CPT_Dropdown_Data` and also injects a javascript file in the way I described above, in which you can capture the click event of the checkboxes and change the dropdown data

Comment: Anyway , thanks so much ,  i use a child theme  for this! 
For the javascript  i add it, with a function on function.php and i can specify the page where it's display also .  

Thanks one more time .

Comment: Ah, that's great! Then you can make your own php ánd javascript functions. 
So now it's basically this:  (1) get taxonomies data for all CPT into javascript arrays (2) handle click on CPT checkbox in javascript and substitute dropdowns data. 
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for all !